# Run script with variables from package.json?

Tags: node.js, bash, package.json

I work on a Node.js project and often run a command in bash which looks like this:

```
path/to/file/1 --flags path/to/file/2 --flags somecommand
```

The command is mostly the same, I only change `path/to/file/2` all the time. Now I would like to implement a script into my `package.json` file so I can run something like this:

```
npm run scriptcommand path/to/file/2
```

I don't know much about bash but I feel like I would need something like this in my `package.json` file:

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "scriptcommand": "path/to/file/1 --flags $1 --flags somecommand"
  }
}
```

Is there any posibility to substitute `path/to/file/2` with a variable like in the above example so I can set a different path on every run?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a new file to hold your script

scriptcommand.sh

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
path/to/file/1 --flags $1 --flags somecommand
```

probably need to chmod it

`sudo chmod +x scriptcommand.sh`

package.json

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "scriptcommand": "scriptcommand.sh"
  }
}
```

And then to run it use

`npm run scriptcommand -- "path/to/file/2"`

Notice the `--` this tells npm to pass along any remaining arguments to your script.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following:

```
"scripts": {
    "scriptcommand": "/bin/echo --flags $FLAGS --flags somecommand"},
```

> FLAGS="path/to/file/2" npm run scriptcommand

Essentially, you set an environment variable, which you use in your scripts command.

Comment: Strange. What OS/bash versions do you use? And can you paste the exact command you are trying to call?

You could also try:

`FLAGS="path/to/file/2"; npm run scriptcommand`

(with ';') Note that this however will leave the variable set for subsequent commands, unless you unset/change its value.